# Implications of increasing igmp_max_memberships

Tags: socket, multicast

I am writing an application that will subscribe to 150+ multicast groups. It appears the linux default number of multicast subscriptions is 20 which can be increased via

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships=new_limit`

Anyone have any experience with any performance implications of increasing this and subscribing to many mcast groups over one socket?  Is it best to split the subscriptions up over many sockets?  If so, why?

Comment: Any updates on this topic?